# unable to find component.jsx in react app

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am getting

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> 'views/Components/Components.jsx in project directory/src/routes'

**routes.jsx**

```
import Components from "../views/Components/Components.jsx";
```

**index.jsx**

```
import Components from "views/Components/Components.jsx";

import LandingPage from "views/LandingPage/LandingPage.jsx";


var indexRoutes = [
  { path: "/landing-page", name: "LandingPage", component: LandingPage },

  { path: "/", name: "Components", component: Components }
];

export default indexRoutes;
```

**Directory hierarchy is as follows**

`routes` folder has :

> index.jsx, dashboard.jsx, headerRoute.jsx and Routes.jsx
>
> views> components > Component.jsx

Comment: You can attach the screenshot of your project structure

Comment: edited the question pls chk image

Answer (score 0):

Change name of Components.jsx because it is predefined for react component

```
import ComponentsName from "../views/Components/ComponentsName
```

Comment: add screenshot of your project structure @allabtcoding

Comment: import Components from "../views/Components/Components"

Comment: @allabtcoding i update my reponce , delete '.jsx' from compontns.jsx

Comment: @allabtcoding delete   '.jsx' from '/LandingPage.jsx"' in                                           
    import LandingPage from "views/LandingPage/LandingPage.jsx";

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the import statement to this?

```
import Components from "../views/Components/Components"
```

Comment: now getting for Can't resolve 'views/LandingPage/LandingPage'